# Cannot convert the expression's type 'StaticString' to type 'StringLiteralConvertible' (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, generics, swift, swift-playground

Generics in a programming language that runs on iOS? Shut up and take my money!

Here's my experimental code (this is running in a playground):

```
class Foo<GenericType1> {
    var value:GenericType1?
    init(value:GenericType1) {
        self.value = value;
    }
}

class Foo2<GenericType2> : Foo<GenericType2> {
    override init(value:GenericType2) {
        super.init(value:value);
    }
}

extension Foo {
    class func floop<T>(value: T) -> Foo2<T> {
        return Foo2<T>(value:value)
    }
}
```

Followed by:

```
var foo = Foo.floop("test")
```

The last part throws an error message:

```
Cannot convert the expression's type 'StaticString' to type 'StringLiteralConvertible'
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar problem and I could make it work by specifying the type at the moment of instantiating the class, i.e. you must tell what type the generic will have once the class is instantiated, in your case it could be something like this:

```
var foo = Foo<String>.floop("test")  //or,
var foo = Foo<Int>.floop("test")
```

I tried it in your code and it worked in a playground.

Hope this helps!